# Oracle Full Text how to search similar words

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

first off all I am newbie to Oracle Text so please bear with me.
I think that my situation is quite simple to manage, because I have to make a search on two fields of the same table and these fields are quite small.
After reading some articles, I think that CTXCAT index is enough for me, but i don't understand how to search parts of words; for example, if I search 'peak', I would like to be returned words like 'speak' also. Can you help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit below link:

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/ctxcat-primer-090555.html

Some portion from link mentioned above are below.

I want to find all auction items which contains the words "toy" and "dog" but not the phrase "live animal":

```
SELECT item_id, item_desc
 FROM auction WHERE CATSEARCH (item_desc, '(toy dog) | "live animal"', null) > 0;
```

A few points to note:

> 1. ANDed terms do not need the word AND or even an "&" operator. AND is
>      assumed between any adjacent terms.
> 2. NOT is represented by "|" (OR, not
>      used here, is represented by "|").
> 3. Parentheses can be used to group
>      terms.
> 4. Double quotes are used to surround a phrase (otherwise "live
>      animal" would have been read as "live AND animal".

The "null" in the query above is a placeholder for a structured clause. There is no default - if you don't provide any structured clause you MUST put "null" in here.
The structured clause allows you to restrict, or sort, your results. If I wanted to extend the query above to find only items costing less than $100, I could use

```
 WHERE CATSEARCH (item_desc, '(toy dog) | "live animal"', 'price < 100') > 0
```

and if I wanted the results with the newest items first, I could use

```
WHERE CATSEARCH (item_desc, '(toy dog) | "live animal"', 
                   'price < 100 order by start_time desc') > 0
```